# Help me please to install quicktime

Tags: command-line, 16.04, software-installation, apple, quicktime

I use ubuntu 16.04 and I need to install quicktime app to recording the screen of my iOS device

What I did

- downloaded the .bz2 archive - http://www.tucows.com/preview/9912
- unzip it

Then in README file I found that I need to download libmpeg3 before

I have downloaded it and execute `./configure` command and `make` command

Than I came back to quicktime and followed instructions executed `make` within quicktime

I got such log in terminal

```
aleksey@aleksey:~$ cd /home/aleksey/Downloads/Quicktime/quicktime4linux-2.2
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/Quicktime/quicktime4linux-2.2$ make
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create x86_64/c_flags: Directory nonexistent
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create x86_64/lame_flags: Directory nonexistent
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create x86_64/objs: Directory nonexistent
make: *** No rule to make target 'x86_64', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

What am I doing wrong? How I can launch this quicktime app on my ubuntu?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't see you do `make install` with the `libmpeg3`, was it done ?

Comment: @George according to the README, it appears to want its own `libmpeg3` built alongside (i.e. the Makefile refers to `../libmpeg3.x.x.x`)

Answer (score 1):

The specific errors you are getting appear to be the result of a malformed `shell` command at line 233 of the `Makefile`:

```
$(shell if ! test -d $(OBJDIR) \; then mkdir -p $(DIRS) \; fi )
```

You need to remove the backslash escapes before the semicolons<sup>1</sup>:

```
$(shell if ! test -d $(OBJDIR) ; then mkdir -p $(DIRS) ; fi )
```

Bear in mind that this appears to be old possibly unmaintained code (the files in the tarball date from 2002-2003) so there may be other errors that you will need to deal with.

---

<sup>1</sup>  I can't find a reference that describes the escaping rules, I'm just basing this on the fact that semicolons aren't escaped elsewhere in the file, and the error appears to go away when they're removed